# using current item from foreach loop in component in code section

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-client-side

Quick question...

Is the following code "legal" in Blazor? I mean can I trust that the `currentTag` variable will always be right, or do I have to "lock" it someway? Not sure how else to get the current item from the loop and use it in the code.

I have a foreach loop on a component and then saving the current item to a variable in my code below. The variable is used immediately after to bind to another childcomponent

```cs
@if (DataTags != null)
{
    @foreach (var dataTag in DataTags)
    {
       // Set currentDataTag 
       @{currentDataTag = dataTag;
        }
          <TagValueForm @bind-TagKeyValuePair="TagKeyValuePair" DataTag="dataTag"></TagValueForm>
    }
}

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public ICollection<Tag> DataTags { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public IDictionary<string, string> Tags { get; set; } 

    // Use the current tag:
    private Tag currentDataTag;

    private KeyValuePair<string, string> _tagKeyValuePair;
    private KeyValuePair<string, string> TagKeyValuePair
    {
        get
        {
            if (currentDataTag != null) //would never be null.. or?
            {
                return new KeyValuePair<string, string>(Tags.Keys.Where(x => x == currentDataTag.Name).FirstOrDefault(), Tags[currentDataTag.Name]);
            }
            else
            {
                return _tagKeyValuePair;
            }
        }
        set
        {
            //Update tag dictionary
            _tagKeyValuePair = value;
            Tags[_tagKeyValuePair.Key] = _tagKeyValuePair.Value;
            TagsChanged.InvokeAsync(Tags);
        }
    }


}


protected async override Task OnParametersSetAsync()
    {
        if (Tags == null)
        {
            Tags = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        }

        if (DataTags != null)
        {
            Tags = DataTags.ToDictionary(x => x.Name, x => { return Tags.ContainsKey(x.Name) ? Tags[x.Name] : null; });
        }


        await base.OnParametersSetAsync();
    }
```

It seems to work with my tests so far, but unsure if I'm just lucky :) Could try to do some delays here and there to test more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `@foreach` block is setting the `currentDataTag` field for every iteration, so in the end the value for the last iteration is where it stops. Your code is working, which is good, but now you have a field with a value that could misrepresent what you are trying to do later on.

I'd probably remove this part:

```cs
// Set currentDataTag 
@{currentDataTag = dataTag;
}
```

and find a way to do everything that needed to be done originally with `currentDataTag` in the same loop iteration. If it's bound to another component, render that component also inside the loop. That way you can avoid any issues that *could* arise as a result of depending on state outside the loop, i.e. what if that value was changed from somewhere else, or read from at an unexpected time.

As a last resort, at the end of each loop iteration, set that `currentDataTag` to null or a base value so you can't read stale or incorrect data later on. Post some more code for us for better context if this doesn't help.

Comment: Thanks Nik. Yes normally I would just call some method in the iteration and pass in the current item, ex an onclick or onchange event. But I can't figure out how to do that for this component, only binding to a property where I can't pass in anything (or can I?). Besides I'd like to learn if there are ways to get the current iteration-item in a safe way outside of the loop.